# Is the cohomology of Hilbert modular surfaces spanned by special cycles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, modular-forms, shimura-varieties

We consider the Hilbert modular surface $X$ that parametrize abelian surface with real multiplication by $\mathcal{O}_F$ and $\mathfrak{a}$-polarization, where $F$ is a real quadratic field with discriminant $D$.( see section 2 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08154.pdf)). On the surface we can define special cycles $T(Dr)$, which parametrize abelian surfaces with special endomorphism $s$ such that $s \circ s=rNm(\mathfrak{a})\mathrm{Id}$.

Now the question is that do we have a nice way to characterize the subspace of cohomology of $X$ spanned by the special cycles? In particular, is the whole cohomology group generated by special cycles? If not, can we describe the complement?

And how is this related to [Zucker's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C2%B2_cohomology#:%7E:text=Another%20such%20result%20is%20the,Borel%20compactification%20(Zucker%201982).)?

Comment: If the cohomology was spanned by cycles, then the etale cohomology (as a Galois representation) would be built from twists of Artin representations. But there are definitely examples where this cannot happen. For instance, if there is an elliptic curve $E/F$ with good reduction everywhere, then the twisted tensor induction of $V_p E$ from $F$ to $\mathbf{Q}$ appears in $H^2(X,\mathbf{Q}_p)$.